# How use Facebook and google+ login in sylius alpha version? can anyone provide simple guide for it?

Tags: symfony, sylius

Can anyone provide me a simplest guide for Facebook and google+ Login or connect for Sylius base project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just started writing a guide to the Sylius docs. I am using [this guide](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/11/13/symfony2-facebook-google-login/) now. I will give more feedback about it next week. Follow Sylius github :)

**EDIT**:

We've just updated the documantation at Sylius. [Check it out here!](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/facebook-login.html)

Comment: Thanks for your soonest response. Secondly i have used this guide (http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/11/13/symfony2-facebook-google-login/) but no luck for sylius. I need some tutorial for Sylius social login.

Comment: [Here it is. A PR to Sylius docs](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/6716) with a cookbook for configuring Social login.

Comment: @CoderMaggie You should update your original answer with the link to the docs. ;)

Comment: @CoderMaggie, this link is dead